# Starting CLI application programmatically does not work depending on arguments

Tags: c#, .net, putty, processstartinfo

I try to start `plink.exe` (PuTTY Link, the command line utility/version of PuTTY) from a C# application to establish an SSH reverse tunnel, **but it does no longer work as soon as I pass the correct parameters**.

What does that mean? The following works as expected: it opens a command line window, displays that I forgot to pass the password for the `-pw` argument quits, and shows the prompt. I know it got the arguments, since it specifically requests the one thing I did not provide.

```
Uri uri = omitted;
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd";
info.Arguments = "/k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\plink.exe\" -R 3389:" + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port + " -N -l username -pw"; // TODO pwd
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

I tried the same think with calling `plink.exe` directly instead of `cmd.exe /k`, but the window closes immediately, which is unfortunate for bug-hunting.

BUT when I pass a password in the arguments, `plink.exe` displays the program help (showing available parameters) and quits:

```
Uri uri = omitted;
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "cmd";
info.Arguments = "/k \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PuTTY\\plink.exe\" -R 3389:" + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port + " -N -l username -pw secretpassword";
Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

No indication of missing parameters. Both the `cmd /k` and `plink.exe` variants do not work (the latter closes immediately, so no information regarding different behaviour).

When I launch the application from the Windows 7 Start Menu launcher with the identical parameters, it opens a `cmd.exe` window and establishes the connection as requested.

What's wrong? Is there a way `plink.exe` notices it's not running in a real shell? If yes, how can I circumvent it, like the Start Menu "prompt" does?

I hope this question is right on SO, since it, though specifically for a single application, revolves around launching it successfully programmatically.

Comment: Thanks I know, but none of the replies helped me there, I still suspect e.g. runtime problems for the Silverlight-related questions and had to create ugly hacks.

All the code I use is shown (copied it into main() for a test), except entering Host and Port of the Uri object I abuse for this task, and the actual username and password for the SSH connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [this web page](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/06/06/how-to-setup-non-interactive-ssh-login/) suggests that Putty gets edgy about non-interactive logons.  If the suggested workaround doesn't help, I recommend you ask questions about it at a Putty support forum or Superuser.com.  It's got otherwise nothing to do with the Process class or the C# language.

Comment: Rewrote the call the plink to use a keyfile and it works. I'm not sure this is the reason it does, but it's the sane thing to do anyway. Thanks!